# Unable to run PHP 7.1 files from Apache

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, apache2.4, ec2-ami

I have setup Apache2.4 with PHP7.1 on Ec2 instance. I am using Amazon Linux versin which comes up with user `ec2-user`. When I browse file, it shows the content of php file. I tried `sudo yum install libapache2-mod-php7.1` but it was not found.

Comment: @meda `yum` works only

Comment: `yum update` then `yum search libapache2-mod-php7.1`

Comment: It is not there

Comment: can you show your apache config

Comment: @meda which section exactly?

Comment: idk, Im thinking perhaps php is installed (confirm with `php -v`). but apache is not configured correctly

Comment: @meda php is definitely installed.